# Change Cluetip background-image during run-time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cluetip

I would like to conditionally change the background image of my Cluetips during run-time via jQuery. I use 'rounded' as cluetipClass.

I thought this would do the trick:

```
$('.cluetip-rounded').css("background", "url(infobox_left.png)");
```

But in the Chrome Developer Toolbar, I can see that the CSS settings are completely untouched.

How can I change the cluetip CSS-settings?

Best,
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work. Make sure you have a correct image path. Look at this:
http://jsfiddle.net/DRN3P/

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$('.cluetip-rounded').css("background-image", "url(infobox_left.png)");
```

and make sure path of image is valid.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Image path is valid, and if I address other classes, it works perfectly. Only for .cluetip-rounded, it does not work.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

cluetip "clones" the hidden div, make sure you invoke the cluetip again after changing the class or alter the "cloned" content.